# Всегда ли нужно тире при пропущенном слове?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, однородные-члены

У меня есть следующая конструкция с однородными членами:

> К разным людям нужен разный подход.
>   с мягкими важно аккуратно лавировать, чтобы они не расстроились и не потеряли мотивацию, с азартными — подпитывать их мотивацию активными поощрениями и сравнением с конкурентами.

Нужно ли тире после "мягкими"? Теоретически там пропущено "люди", значит может быть тире. С другой стороны, оно тут кажется избыточным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там тире не обязательно. Если поставить, то получится, что после *азартными* пропущены аж два слова: *людьми важно*. А два тире подряд не поставить.

При пропущенном слове тире ставится, если есть параллелизм (предложения очень похожи по структуре):
с мягкими важно аккуратно лавировать;
с азартными — [важно] подпитывать их мотивацию.

Розенталь:
Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается пауза:
*Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно плохо.

Мы взялись за дело весело, они — даже с энтузиазмом.

Идти дальше через трясину было опасно, оставаться — тоже.

Такую температуру могут выдержать только сплавы стали, а из лёгких металлов — только сплавы титана.

Вы здесь уже давно, а я — только несколько дней.*

Но даже для этой, казалось бы, строгой закономерности сделано примечание, что при отсутствии паузы тире не ставится:
*Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку.

Из нашей батареи только Солёный пойдёт на барже, мы же со строевой частью.

Алёша смотрел на них, а они на него.

У вора один грех, а у нас с хозяином десять.

Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93